# jmeter response code 204 and can't get content

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am doing a websocket stress test through jmeter2.9.
When I send a request and response with a "light" json. the result is ok.
But when the response json contains a base64 png(about 360kb) . jmeter return code 204 No content (probably timeout).

Is my jmeter need some config here, or something else wrong.
If someone know something about this please teach me.

complete info:

Thread Name: threadgroup 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-07-17 15:36:06 CST
Load time: 20000
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 204
Response message: No content (probably timeout).

Response headers:

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding:

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using Cache manager, there seems to be a (bug) in Jmeter that sets the response code to HTTP Code '204' ("No Response") while, there is no outgoing request, the information is retrieved from the Cache, try disabling cache manager and lets see if you can reproduce it then.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the unhandled exception, response being larger than the maximum message size specified in the plugin code, etc. The exception which you see will be thrown if no response has been received from the server after predefined timeout.

Here is another WebSocket plugin for JMeter which might work for you

Link: https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter

Features:

- Supports HTTS/HTTPS (ws/wss) version of the WebSocket protocol
- Option to ignore SSL certificate errors
- Streaming allows for a single connection to remain open for the duration of the test
- Response has to match predefined regular expression
- Response timeout
- Response message back log (build the Sampler response from multiple server messages)
- Connection could be closed if server sends a mesage matching predefined regular expression